# Qt C++ : To delete or not to delete

Tags: c++, qt

I create a little app with 3 QMainWindow, each time I click the red cross to close a window, I call my destructor to delete each QPushButton, each QLabel and other.

Do I have to delete everything or Qt can do it for me ? (I read somewhere everything created with "this" (parent) will be deleted automatically but i'm not sure)

My problem is when I close my program I have a double free or corruption.
Valgrind does not say me when comes the problem and I try to remove all my delete and nothing change.

Any idea?

if this could be clearer for you : git@github.com:q7frkz/Qt_mytest.git

To explain following code:
A MainWindow with 3 QPushbutton, only the second interest us now.
By clicking, on the second, a new Window appear with choice, Server or client.

client isn't implemented only server is.

Gpsinfo is a circular chained list which is displayed in a Qlabel named labelDown in BServer.cpp, it contains GPS coordinates.

GPS is a global QVector = {"gps_coordinates","gps_coordinates",....}

(Sorry for my English)
If you have any questions.

main.cpp

```
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    b1 = new QPushButton("Test RGB", this);
    b1->setGeometry(50, 25, 400, 50);
    b1->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    connect(b1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(rgb()));

    b2 = new QPushButton("Bilberry", this);
    b2->setGeometry(50, 100, 400, 50);
    b2->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    connect(b2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(bilberry()));

    b3 = new QPushButton("Next", this);
    b3->setGeometry(50, 175, 400, 50);
    b3->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));

    box = new QVBoxLayout();
    box->addWidget(b1);
    box->addWidget(b2);
    box->addWidget(b3);
}

//Menu::~Menu()
//{
//    qDebug() << "Delete menu";
//    delete b1;
//    delete b2;
//    delete b3;
//    delete box;
//    qDebug() << "Fin Delete menu";
//}

void Menu::rgb()
{
    auto *w = new RGB(this);
    w->setWindowTitle("RGB");
    w->setFixedSize(500, 500);
    w->show();
}

void Menu::bilberry()
{
    auto *bil = new Bilberry(this);
    bil->setWindowTitle("Bilberry");
    bil->setFixedSize(500, 175);
    bil->show();
}
```

bilberry.cpp

```
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    b1 = new QPushButton("Test RGB", this);
    b1->setGeometry(50, 25, 400, 50);
    b1->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    connect(b1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(rgb()));

    b2 = new QPushButton("Bilberry", this);
    b2->setGeometry(50, 100, 400, 50);
    b2->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    connect(b2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(bilberry()));

    b3 = new QPushButton("Next", this);
    b3->setGeometry(50, 175, 400, 50);
    b3->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));

    box = new QVBoxLayout();
    box->addWidget(b1);
    box->addWidget(b2);
    box->addWidget(b3);
}

//Menu::~Menu()
//{
//    qDebug() << "Delete menu";
//    delete b1;
//    delete b2;
//    delete b3;
//    delete box;
//    qDebug() << "Fin Delete menu";
//}

void Menu::rgb()
{
    auto *w = new RGB(this);
    w->setWindowTitle("RGB");
    w->setFixedSize(500, 500);
    w->show();
}

void Menu::bilberry()
{
    auto *bil = new Bilberry(this);
    bil->setWindowTitle("Bilberry");
    bil->setFixedSize(500, 175);
    bil->show();
}
```

bilberry.h

```
#ifndef BILBERRY_H
#define BILBERRY_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "BServer.h"


class Bilberry : public  QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Bilberry(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
//        ~Bilberry();

    public slots:
        void B_Server();
        void B_Client();

    private:
        QPushButton *client;
        QPushButton *server;
        BServer *bserver;
};


#endif //TUTO2_BILBERRY_H
```

BServer.cpp

```
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QString>
#include <QRandomGenerator>

#include "global.h"
#include "BServer.h"

BServer::BServer(QMainWindow *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    labelTop = new QLabel(this);
    labelTop->resize(500, 100);
    labelTop->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    labelTop->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBaseline);
    labelTop->setText("Waiting connection on localhost:4242\n");
    labelTop->show();

    labelDown = new QLabel(this);
    labelDown->resize(500, 400);
    labelDown->move(0, 100);
    labelDown->setFont(QFont("Times", 13, QFont::Bold));
    labelDown->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBaseline);

    qsrand(time(nullptr));
    createCircularGPSInfo();
    initGPSTimer();

    _server = new QTcpServer(this);
    _server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 4242);

    connect(_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
    //connect(_server, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    //connect(this, SIGNAL(close()), this, BServer::~BServer());
}

//BServer::~BServer()
//{
//    qDebug() << "Debut delete";
//    timer->stop();
//    delete timer;
//    _server->close();
//    delete _server;
//    delete labelTop;
//    delete labelDown;
//    info->prev->next = nullptr;
//    delete info;
//    qDebug() << "Fin delete";
//}

void BServer::onNewConnection()
{
    labelTop->setText("Waiting connection on localhost:4242<br />New Connection");
}

//void BServer::onReadyRead()
//{
//    labelTop->setText("Connected");
//}

void BServer::createCircularGPSInfo()
{
    info = new GPSInfo();
    GPSInfo *tmp = info;
    for (int count = 0 ; count < 19 ; ++count) {
        tmp->next = new GPSInfo();
        tmp->next->prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = info;
    info->prev = tmp;
}

QString *BServer::getInfo()
{
    QString *data = new QString();
    GPSInfo *tmp = info;
    while (tmp->prev && tmp->prev->getInfo().size())
    {
        data->push_back(tmp->prev->getInfo());
        data->push_back("<br/>");
        tmp = tmp->prev;
        if (tmp == info)
            break;
    }
    return data;
}

void BServer::initGPSTimer()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showGPS()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void BServer::showGPS()
{
    info->setInfo(GPS[qrand() % 17]);
    info = info->next;

    labelDown->setText(*(getInfo()));
}
```

BServer.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QString>

#include "GPSInfo.h"

#ifndef BSERVER_H
#define BSERVER_H


class BServer : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit BServer(QMainWindow *parent = nullptr);
        //~BServer();

    public slots:
        void onNewConnection();
        //void onReadyRead();
        void showGPS();

    private:
        QTcpServer *_server;
        QLabel *labelTop;
        QLabel *labelDown;
        GPSInfo *info;
        QTimer *timer;
        QString *getInfo();
        void createCircularGPSInfo();
        void initGPSTimer();


};


#endif //BSERVER_H
´´´
gpsinfo.cpp
´´´
#include "GPSInfo.h"

void GPSInfo::setInfo(QString &info)
{
    _info = info;
}

const QString &GPSInfo::getInfo()
{
    return _info;
}
```

GPSInfo.cpp

```
#include "GPSInfo.h"

void GPSInfo::setInfo(QString &info)
{
    _info = info;
}

const QString &GPSInfo::getInfo()
{
    return _info;
}
```

GPSInfo.h

```
#ifndef GPSINFO_H
#define GPSINFO_H

#include <QString>

#include "GPSInfo.h"

class GPSInfo
{
    public:
        GPSInfo() {};
        //~GPSInfo() {if (next) delete next;};
        void setInfo(QString &);
        const QString &getInfo();
        GPSInfo *next = nullptr;
        GPSInfo *prev = nullptr;
    private:
        QString _info;
};


#endif //GPSINFO_H
´´´
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You may want to use [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) however it's difficult to help without a minimal example. Qt will not double delete if you delete a child that has a parent. The parent will know when the child is deleted and it will remove it from the list of objects under its lifetime management.

Comment: No-one can tell you about your code unless you post your code. The details matter, so don't talk in general terms, post the code you have.

Comment: I expect you will have to use a debugger.

Comment: ***My problem is when I close my program I have a double free or corruption*** This is a typical symptom of a violation of the rule of 3 /5 /0. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: `Menu::~Menu()` should not exist. No need to delete any of the widgets.

Comment: @drescherjm ah ! that interests me

Comment: The comment about the rule of 3/5/0 most likely does not apply to QObect based objects because you don't copy or assign them. [https://www.cleanqt.io/blog/why-qobject-subclasses-are-not-copyable](https://www.cleanqt.io/blog/why-qobject-subclasses-are-not-copyable) I mentioned the rule because perhaps you have some other class that does not derive from QObject.

Comment: only GPSInfo yes

Comment: `//~GPSInfo() {if (next) delete next;};` may have been a problem. I assume this code was not commented out at some point.

Comment: when I want to delete this, i do in the code x->prev->next = nullptr and after delete > {if (next) delete next;} > tlike this I delete all chained list
You can see it in BServer.cpp in the destructor

Comment: That would likely cause a memory leak (because you don't free any other `GPSInfo` objects in the list) but not a double delete.

Comment: maybe that could help you
git@github.com:q7frkz/Qt_mytest.git